# SwiftUI: How to get content aligned to top of screen, but keep back button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, alignment

I'm learning SwiftUI (with Swift 5, targeting iOS 13.2)

**Q) How do I get it so that my photo (and contents underneath) are aligned behind the notch area?**

*What I've got so far in the simulator:*

As you can see, I've found out how to use an inline navigation bar style.

[image]

*What I want*

[image]

**View Code:**

```
import SwiftUI

struct DrinkDetail: View {
    
    var drink: Drink
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                Image(drink.imageName)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 80.0)
                    .opacity(0.75)
                    .blur(radius: 10)
                
                HStack {
                    Text(drink.name)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(8)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
                .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            
            Text(drink.description)
                .font(.body)
                .foregroundColor(.primary)
                .lineLimit(nil)
                .padding(.bottom, 50.0)
                .lineSpacing(12)
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Text("Order me")
                }
                    .frame(width: 200.0, height: 50.0)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    
                    
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65523676/12299030?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this simply isn't possible, despite the tutorial I watched showing it previously being possible.

Until further notice, this is the only way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65523676/12299030